# Issue with Synchronous Sequential Circuit using Flip Flop D

Tags: vhdl, state-machine, vivado, flip-flop

Right now i'm working on a project concerning the use of D Flip Flop on Falling Edge, with x and y being the inputs and z being the output.

The Circuit will only give z ='1' only if x and y are both 0 and also if they were both 0 in a previous clock cycle, and the transitions only occurring in the clock's falling edge.

Variables a and b will represent states Q0(a) and Q1(b).

The Mealy machine is of two states : Q0 and Q1, and the transations are as follow:

> Q0
>
> x  y  z
>
> 0  0  1
>
> 0  1  x
>
> 1  0  0 --> goes to next state (Q1)
>
> 1  1  x
>
> Q1
>
> x  y  z
>
> 0  0  0 --> goes to next state (Q0) only this time z='0'
>
> 0  1  x
>
> 1  0  x
>
> 1  1  0 --> stays in current state (Q1)

The problem is that when the transition from Q1 to Q0 happens, z is still '1' instead of '0'.

Is there any advice on how could i manage to get around that fast transition?

Here is the code so far:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Mealys is
  Port (
    inicio: in std_logic;
    clk: in std_logic;
    x: in std_logic;
    y: in std_logic;
    z: out std_logic;
    a: out  std_logic;
    b: out std_logic
  );
end Mealys;

architecture behavior of Mealys is

  type nombres_estados is (Q0, Q1);
  signal estado: nombres_estados;
  signal entrada_aux: std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);

begin

  entrada_aux <= x & y;

  FF_D: process (clk)
  begin
    if (inicio = '1') then
      estado <= Q0;
    elsif falling_edge(clk) then
      case estado is
        when Q0 =>
          case entrada_aux is
            when "00" => estado<=Q0;
            when "10" => estado<=Q1;
            when others => estado<=Q0;
          end case;
        when Q1 =>
          case entrada_aux is
            when "00" => estado<=Q0;
            when "11" => estado<=Q1;
            when others => estado<=Q1;
          end case;
        when others => estado<=Q0;
      end case;
    end if;
  end process;

  next_decode: process(estado, entrada_aux)
  begin
    case (estado) is
      when Q0 =>
        a <= '1';
        b <= '0';
        if entrada_aux <= "00" then
          z<='1';
        elsif entrada_aux <= "10" then
          z<='0';
        end if;
      when Q1 =>
        a <= '0';
        b <= '1';
        if entrada_aux <= "00" then
          z<='0';
        elsif entrada_aux <= "11" then
          z<='0';
        end if;
    end case;
  end process;

end behavior;
```

And here is the state diagram
[image]

Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are learning VHDL, that you are starting with the VHDL subset for synthesis and that the final goal is to synthesize your design.

Your design comprises two processes: a synchronous one and a combinatorial one. Both are bogus for synthesis.

1. Your synchronous process does not correctly handle the reset. If your reset is asynchronous (that is, is taken into account immediately when asserted), it should be in the sensitivity list:

   ```
   process(clk, inicio)
   begin
     if inicio = '1' then
       <initialize things>
     elsif falling_edge(clk) then
       <do things>
     end if;
   end process;
   ```

   And if it is synchronous (that is taken into account only on the clock falling edge), it should not be in the sensitivity list but the reset part of your process should be under the scope of the clock edge test:

   ```
   process(clk)
   begin
     if falling_edge(clk) then
       if inicio = '1' then
         <initialize things>
       else
         <do things>
       end if;
     end if;
   end process;
   ```
2. Your combinatorial process has 3 outputs: `a`, `b`and `z`. They **must all be assigned a value during any execution of the process**. This is what combinatorial means: each time an input changes, the signals propagate and all outputs finally get a new value. The *new* value can be the same as the previous one but this must be by accident, not because the output has not been assigned. Else, it would mean to a synthesizer: "*keep the previous value*", which usually leads to the inference of latches to store the previous value... Not what you want in a true combinatorial process. In your process, when `estado` or `entrada_aux` change, `a` and `b` are assigned but not always `z` (I let you understand why).

   There is another problem in this process: the equality test operator is `=`, not `<=` which is the less or equal test operator. Note that your code should not even compile as it is.

   It is not easy to propose a fixed version of this process because your specification is not 100% clear. What do these `x` mean in the transition table? For instance, what happens to `z` if we are in state `Q0` and `xy` is `01` or `11`? If the answer is "*`z` does not change*", then its computation must involve a memory element and you must describe this in your synchronous process. Else, if it means "*`z` takes any value*" (we don't care), then you must decide yourself before coding and add this to your combinatorial process (for instance with an `else` statement).

   I will assume that it means "*`z` does not change*". So, you need a memory element (a D-flip-flop) to store the previous value. Add another signal (`previous_z`) and assign it in your synchronous process:

   ```
   signal previous_z: std_logic:
   ...
   process(clk, inicio)
   begin
     if inicio = '1' then
       previous_z <= '0';
       <initialize other things>
     elsif falling_edge(clk) then
       previous_z <= z;
       <do other things>
     end if;
   end process;
   ```

   There is a potential problem here because we are reading the value of `z` which is an output port of your entity. In VHDL versions previous 2008 this was forbidden. If you are using a pre-2008 version of VHDL you must declare another internal signal (`local_z`) that you can read and assign, use it everywhere, and assign it to the output `z`, for instance in a concurrent signal assignment (outside any process):

   ```
   signal previous_z: std_logic:
   signal local_z: std_logic:
   ...
   process(clk, inicio)
   begin
     if inicio = '1' then
       previous_z <= '0';
       <initialize other things>
     elsif falling_edge(clk) then
       previous_z <= local_z;
       <do other things>
     end if;
   end process;

   z <= local_z;
   ```

   Now, you can use this `previous_z` signal in your combinatorial process to compute `local_z` (or `z` in VHDL 2008):

   ```
   next_decode: process(estado, entrada_aux, previous_z)
   begin
     case estado is
       when Q0 =>
         a <= '1';
         b <= '0';
         if entrada_aux = "00" then
           local_z <= '1';
         elsif entrada_aux = "10" then
           local_z <= '0';
         else
           local_z <= previous_z;
         end if;
       when Q1 =>
         a <= '0';
         b <= '1';
         if entrada_aux = "00" then
           local_z <= '0';
         elsif entrada_aux = "11" then
           local_z <= '0';
         else
           local_z <= previous_z;
         end if;
     end case;
   end process;
   ```

   Note that `previous_z` must be added to the sensitivity list. Do you see now how the `local_z` output of the process will always be assigned?

   There is an even better option which consists in assigning a default value to each output, unconditionally, at the beginning of the process and change this if and only if needed:

   ```
   next_decode: process(estado, entrada_aux, previous_z)
   begin
     a <= '0':
     b <= '0';
     local_z <= previous_z;
     case estado is
       when Q0 =>
         a <= '1';
         if entrada_aux = "00" then
           local_z <= '1';
         elsif entrada_aux = "10" then
           local_z <= '0';
         end if;
       when Q1 =>
         b <= '1';
         if entrada_aux = "00" then
           local_z <= '0';
         elsif entrada_aux = "11" then
           local_z <= '0';
         end if;
     end case;
   end process;
   ```

   This works because, in a combinatorial process, when a signal is assigned several times, it is the last assignment that *wins*. And this coding style has a good property: you cannot forget to assign an output.

   There is another good option: concurrent signal assignments (outside any process):

   ```
   a <= '1' when estado = Q0 else '0';
   b <= '1' when estado = Q1 else '0';
   local_z <= '1' when estado = Q0 and entrada_aux = "00" else
              '0' when estado = Q0 and entrada_aux = "10" else
              '0' when estado = Q1 and entrada_aux = "00" else
              '0' when estado = Q1 and entrada_aux = "11" else
              previous_z;
   ```

   Concurrent signal assignments, when the logic is simple enough, are maybe even better than the two other options because there is no need to worry about sensitivity lists and always assigning the outputs. Probably very good points, at least for beginners.

One last remark: you use the `std_logic` resolved type without any good reason. This is unfortunate and error prone. You should use `std_ulogic`, its unresolved parent type instead (`u` for **U**nresolved). But this is out of scope your question.